# How to query a json in postgres using Op.iLike in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, jsonb, query-string

My table called 'notifications' has the following columns/attributes :
targetPage -> integer
notificationDescription -> JSONB

Here notificationDescription has 3 attributes in it i.e title, body and media.
So I need to query data that is in title and body so I did the below code:

```
await this.customerNotificationRepository.findAndCountAll({
    where: {
        notificationDescription: {
            title: {
                [Op.iLike]: `%${searchKey}%`,
            },
            body: {
                [Op.iLike]: `%${searchKey}%`,
            },
        },

    }
});
```

---

The 'searchKey' in the above code is taken from queryParams.

I always get the empty as result even if I search with the key the is present in the database
{
"code": 200,
"message": "Notifications fetched successfully",
"data": []
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[Op.contains]` on jsonb in postgres. Try something like,

```
await this.customerNotificationRepository.findAndCountAll({
where: {
    notificationDescription: {
        [Op.contains]: {
           title: {
             [Op.iLike]: `%${searchKey}%`,
           },
           body: {
            [Op.iLike]: `%${searchKey}%`,
           },
        }
    },
  }
});
```